# Quantum key distribution using BB84 protocol

Tags: entropy, quantum-cryptography, quantum-key-distribution

Quantum key distribution using BB84 protocol. The Secure key rate $R$, is  given by

$$ \quad R=1 - 2h(e_b) \tag{1}\label{q1}$$

where $e_b$ is the quantum bit error rate (QBER), $h(x)$ is the [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shannon_entropy) and is $h(x)=-x  \log_{2}(x)-(1-x)\log_{2}(1-x)$.

How do we calculate the threshold for BB84 using equation $\eqref{q1}$?

What is the physical meaning of Shannon entropy?

Comment: This is about quantum-key-distribution, has strictly nothing to do with post-quantum-cryptography or quantum-cryptanalysis, and is only remotely about encryption.

Comment: Could you please expand on _"What is the physical meaning of Shannon entropy?"_

Comment: I'm not certain if the above formula (with the variable definitions) makes sense.  $e_b$ is presumably a real number; Shannon entropy is defined over probability distributions; a real number is not a probability distribution...

Comment: What do you mean by "threshold for BB84"? Equation (1) gives you the rate of key bits per use of the quantum channel that you can get when the channel has an error rate $e_b$, i.e. as the noise on the channel increases, the number of key bits per channel use decreases.